Necessity of Banach category for K-theory
In Karoubi's book on K-Theory (K-Theory, An Introduction), he introduces the groups $K^{p,q}(C)$ for a pseudo-abelian Banach category $C$.
My question is whether the requirement that $C$ be a Banach category can be reformulated in a more algebraic way?
I understand that Karoubi uses the topological nature of Banach categories to talk about elementary objects which are used to define the K-group. But the first time I saw K-groups (of vector bundles), the equivalence relation was defined using exact sequences. Is there a way of approaching the groups $K^{p,q}$ in that way, too?

Whick book of Karoubi are you refering to? I do not see Banach categories in Homologie cyclique et K-théorie.

@Z.M: I think the book is Karoubi - K-Theory, An Introduction (1978).
